# lxc container no outgoing traffic

Tags: network-bridge, lxc

I am trying to setup a lxc container on a ubuntu 13.04 on a linode VPS, but I can't ping anything outside my host.

my container network config looks like this:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:04:93:57
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.0.3.3/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 10.0.3.1
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
```

I have add the two lines with ipv4 my self, without them I couldn’t event ping the host.

On the host side ifconfig show this for the bridge and container interface:

```
lxcbr0: Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:b2:8c:74:8c:fa  
inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::68aa:7eff:feb4:9959/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:7179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:2294800 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:846 (846.0 B)

vethYNhCg1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:b2:8c:74:8c:fa  
inet6 addr: fe80::fcb2:8cff:fe74:8cfa/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:64446 (64.4 KB)  TX bytes:2904 (2.9 KB)
```

The veth interface doesn’t get a ipv4 IP automaticly, I have tried to add one my self but it didn’t help.

dmesg logs lines like this:

```
[1466355.530226] iptables denied: IN=lxcbr0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:04:93:57:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=328 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=308
```

I have tried allot of different things but nothing seems to work. This is what I have tried so fare.

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vethYNhCg1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lxcbr0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lxcbr0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Unfortunately I do not know a hole lot about networking so I am just trying anything I can find. Please help.

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue. I see the DHCP traffic being blocked there. What are your current firewall rules? Post the output of `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t NAT -L -n -v` (and if the output is very long, post it on http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: The output from iptables -L -n -v can be seen here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6051430/. But I get an error when I try to call iptables -t NAT -L -n -v:  iptables v1.4.12: can't initialize iptables table `NAT': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Comment: Your first problem is with the FORWARD chain. The DROP rule takes precedence over the ACCEPT (as you can see in the number of packets being hit by it), because it is listed first. If you don't understand plain `iptables`, then why are you running the firewall in the first place? Or, read up on `iptables`. Oh and sorry, NAT command should have been `sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v`

Comment: Iptables is enabled as default. Is it safe running without a firewall?

Comment: I know `iptables` is enabled by default, but **you** have configured it to DROP packets, this is not default! As this seems very obvious to me, I doubt you understand what you are doing. So that's why I ask if you really need to run this firewall. If you do, then read up on `iptables` or run a `iptables` front-end that makes it a lot easier. Eg.: `shorewall`, `ufw`, and many more exist.

Comment: I did not add the DROP condition, but thanks for the tip about ufw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added two lines in the top of /etc/iptables.firewall.rules:

```
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.3.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT                                     
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.3.0/24 -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

Just below *filter